# How can I add a personalized annotation to a layer? Mapbox [Swift]

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mapbox

How can I add a personalized annotation to a layer?

My custom class:

```
class PointCustom: NSObject, MGLAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var imageURL: URL?
    var typ: PointsType?

    var reuseIdentifier: String?

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String?, subtitle: String?, imageURL: URL?, reuseIdentifier: String?, typ: PointsType?) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.imageURL = imageURL
        self.reuseIdentifier = reuseIdentifier
        self.typ = typ
    }
}


let points = parsePoints()
let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: "points", features: points, options: nil)
```

Problem:
Cannot convert value of type '[PointCustom]' to expected argument type 'MGLShape?'

Comment: Which line gives the error? The error message indicates you are trying to pass an array of PointCustom where an optional MGLShape is expected.

Comment: @Magnas the error is in the last line of the code. Could you explain to me how to add "CustomPoint" to the layer

Comment: Have you checked the Mapbox website they have excellent examples. Customising annotations is covered here: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/maps/examples/

Comment: @Magnas I checked, only that I use a non-standard class and I want my admotations to support Cluster. And I can not find this anywhere